# Including a gobject.h in codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, gobject

I want to make class by using C GObject lib in Codeblocks. So I have 2 classes: A.h and A.c
But when i include gobject lib like this:

```
#include <glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h>
```

It gives me an error:

```
 Only <glib-object.h> can be included directly.
```

Because this file contains these lines:

```
 #if !defined (__GLIB_GOBJECT_H_INSIDE__) && !defined (GOBJECT_COMPILATION)
 #error "Only <glib-object.h> can be included directly."
 #endif
```

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h>
//It's only declaring an class called A

typedef struct _AClass AClass;
typedef struct _A A;

struct _AClass {
     //Always Derived from GObjectClass class
     GObjectClass parent_instance;
}

struct _A{
   //Always Derived from GObject class
   GObject parent_instance;
}

#endif // A_H
```

A.c:

```
#include "/home/alex/GObject_Tutorial/include/A.h"
//It's defining a class called A

G_DEFINE_TYPE(A, aObj, G_TYPE_OBJECT);
```

I think the only way to include these libraries is to add them to local folder and include like (but maybe there is another way):

```
#include "gobject.h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you. So my total answer:
We don't include only gobject/gobject.h, because glib-object.h is aggregator and it contains these all libraries to provide a creating of gobject-class.
My steps:

1) Find where are the libs in glibs using:

```
 pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-2.0
```

So, I've got result (in your case it can be different):

```
 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

2) Then in code::blocks **Project->Build Options->Compiler Settings->Other Options**

3) Copy this line (-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include) in text field

4) Copy to Project->Build Options->Linker Settings->Other Linker Options this line (-lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0)

5) Build

6) Hooray! It works, Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

you should follow the helpful error message instead of trying to work around it.

you cannot include `gobject.h` directly outside of GLib: only `glib-object.h` is meant for inclusion in application code.

you should also use relative paths for non-system header files in your inclusion rules: use the inclusion paths settings in your compiler and/or IDE.